# Python mutiprocessing pool with partial arguments

Tags: python, multiprocessing, closures

So I'm trying to follow the example here:
[Python multiprocessing pool.map for multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments)

What if I have three arguments and I need the third fixed to a value, e.g. some thing like this but it doesn't work. Raise TypeError saying partial_merge() takes exactly 2 arguments but only 1 given.

```
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial


def merge_names(a, b, c):
    return '{} & {} & {}'.format(a, b, c)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    names = [('Brown', 'Wilson'), ('Bartlett', 'Rivera'), ('Molloy', 'Opie')]
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3)

    results = pool.map(partial(merge_names, c='Hello'), names)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(results)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pool.map()` works like the 'normal' `map()`: it takes a function with one missing argument and a list and applies the function to each element of the list. The easiest way to solve your problem would be to modify your function:

```
def merge_names(tup, c):
    a, b = tup
    return '{} & {} & {}'.format(a, b, c)
```

---

Depending on your goal/setting, there are other possibilities (increasing in complexity):

1. closures. Example:

   ```
   def func(x):
       return x + y

   def main():
       y = 5  # the point is to declare this BEFORE Pool() is initiated
       p = mp.Pool(3)
       data = range(10)
       results = p.map(func, data)
   ```
2. shared values: see the [documentation on sharing state](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)
3. queues and pipes: see the [documentation on queues and pipes](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes)
4. not using pool but [`mp.Process()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class) which allows you much finer control of arguments and more.

Comment: It seems like y would be out of scope here. Does y need to be global?